# Keyframes doesn't work when keyframe-class is added

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I have a user card that when gets opened, shows the user's picture.

(https://jsfiddle.net/xv036sny/2/)

This works, but what I want to achieve is to make a more complex animation using CSS Keyframes.

```
.userCard__image-shown{
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Im trying this by adding keyframes to the class **.userCard__image-shown**

```
@keyframes test{
    0% {transform: scale(0.1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.1);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
.userCard__image-shown{
    animation: test 0.2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

The point is that when I'm toggling this class, it doesn't work.
What Im doing wrong?

(I hope you understand my (yet) bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Sometimes browsers don't support all the properties, and you may need to use the vendor prefix to get the best browser support. This is what causes the animation issue.

For example, the animation doesn't work correctly on Chrome, but you can add the `-webkit-` prefix and it will solve the problem:

```
@-webkit-keyframes test{
    0% {transform: scale(0.1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.1);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

.userCard__image-shown{
    animation: test 0.2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation:test 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
}
```

Here is a demo using the code from your JSFiddle (I changed the animation duration to 2 seconds so it can be seen):

```js
$('#userName-1').on('click', function(){
    $( ".userCard" ).toggleClass('userCard-shown').delay( 300 );
    $( ".userCard__image" ).toggleClass('userCard__image-shown');
});
```

```css
body{overflow: hidden;}img{border-radius: 50%;}
.userCard{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    position: absolute;
    right: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.userCard-shown{
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}

.userCard__image{
    padding-top: 32px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0.1);
}

.userCard__image-shown{
    animation: test 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation:test 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
}

@keyframes test{
    0% {transform: scale(0.1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.1);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes test{
    0% {transform: scale(0.1);}
    50% {transform: scale(1.1);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><span id="userName-1">UserName</span></a>

<div class="userCard">
    <div class="userCard__image">
        <img src="//yt3.ggpht.com/-LYuWGoFbuCs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LYsyfZDIHjc/s100-c-k-no/photo.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on JSFiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/xv036sny/3/

Comment: So, canIuse is lying to me!! http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes I thought I did not need prefixes

Comment: It's just a bit "hidden". If you go to that link, you'll see that some of the browsers with a green box have a tiny yellow mark on them, mouse over them and you'll see that it says "Supported with prefix: -webkit-"